# Django Rest Framework: How to enable swagger docs for function based views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

I went through [Django REST Swagger 2.1.2 documentation](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). When I tried with class based views, it was working fine.

But i did not find any reference on how to enable swagger for function based views as shown below:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def app_info(request): 
    ...
    return response
```

Most of my `views.py` is filled with function based views, just like above.

Any help on how to enable the same will greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I am using **Django: 1.8;   Django REST Swagger: 2.1.2;  DRF: 3.6.2**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to use [`@renderer_classes`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators) decorator:

```py
from rest_framework_swagger import renderers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@renderer_classes([renderers.OpenAPIRenderer, renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer])
def app_info(request): 
    ...
    return response
```

Also, it should be worth mentioning, that if you don't want to use this decorator on every view you can specify [`DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` in settings](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers)

EDIT: It seems it's in the docs after all. Check the very bottom of this page: https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema/

Comment: As per your EDIT: How did I miss that..! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

i am not fammiliar with swagger,but you may try to use the decorator in this way:

```
class TestView(View):
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def get(self, request):
        ....
```

or

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
class TestView(View):
    @method_decorator(api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def get(self, request):
        ....
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sorry, maybe i have misunderstood your question. according to the document, if you want to enable swagger in class based view.  there is example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.schemas import SchemaGenerator
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_swagger import renderers


class SwaggerSchemaView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    renderer_classes = [
        renderers.OpenAPIRenderer,
        renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer
    ]

    def get(self, request):
        generator = SchemaGenerator()
        schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)
        return Response(schema)
```

restframework will use these two renderer_classes to render Json and UI.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it try. Most probably it wont work, lets see.

Comment: As per your EDIT: This I already know. My question is how to enable swagger for Function based views.

Comment: Abijith Mg is asking about swagger with function. Not about swagger with classes. With classes Abijith Mg said "it was working fine".

Answer (score 2):

## Add the following in your views.py

### Imports

```
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema
from rest_framework.compat import coreapi
```

```
#creating custom class 
class CustomSampleSchema(AutoSchema):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomSampleSchema, self).__init__()

    def get_manual_fields(self, path, method):
        extra_fields = [
            coreapi.Field('field1', required=True, location='form', description='', type='', example=''),
            coreapi.Field('field2', required=False, location='form', description='', type='', example=''),
            coreapi.Field('field3', required=False, location='form', description='', type='', example='')

        ]
        manual_fields = super().get_manual_fields(path, method)
        return manual_fields + extra_fields
```

### This is the function you're writing swagger doc for.

```
@api_view(['post'])
@schema(CustomSampleSchema())
@csrf_exempt
def func_name(request, param):
"""
Your function definition below
"""
```

### Sample json input

```
{"name": "['name1', ]",
"places": "['place1', 'place2']",
"key":"12345"}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add description and response types?