# How to generate swagger for django rest api where my views are fucntion based view

Tags: django, swagger

I have search so many sites,even document but cannot find a complete steps to create swagger for function based views in django.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627748/django-rest-framework-how-to-enable-swagger-docs-for-function-based-views

Comment: but i need a step by step guide. I am facing problem in POST api. I cannot display the input parameter in swagger UI

Comment: You can find various tutorials for setting up the swagger first. Then you can use the question link mentioned in the above comment to setup for function based views.

Comment: I checked and setup the swagger. my swagger UI is up and running and i am facing problem in the input parameters of the POST api. and also in url.py how to set the schema

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629381/5312750) can help.

Comment: will check and get back to you @SachinKukreja

Comment: this helps. but how can i display file upload ? i have to provide a csv file to the rest api

Comment: guys, can you help?